# Create a view that shows two lists with specific values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want two lists, that both show records from their respective tables that are not being used another table.

Two lists, one for the table **a_aif** and one for the table **a_proxy**. The list to show only those `fee_source_id's` that are not present in the column `a_fees.fee_source`

Here is what I have so far (two separate queries). Any way to make a view with these two lists in separate columns?

```
SELECT a_aif.fee_source_id
FROM a_aif, a_fees
WHERE a_fees.fee_source NOT IN (SELECT a_aif.fee_source_id);

SELECT a_proxy.fee_source_id
FROM a_proxy, a_fees
WHERE a_fees.fee_source NOT IN (SELECT a_proxy.fee_source_id);
```

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It was in his title, I moved it into tags.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks I missed that in the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method should be pretty agnostic to the RDBMS you are using.

A pair of `LEFT JOIN`s from which you select records where the right side is `NULL` will do. A `UNION` query is used to build a master list of ids from both the `a_aif` and `a_proxy` tables.

```
SELECT 
  full_list.fee_source_id,
  CASE WHEN aif_fee_source_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'present' ELSE 'not-present' END AS aif,
  CASE WHEN proxy_fee_source_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'present' ELSE 'not-present' END AS proxy
FROM (
  /* UNION list gets total list of ids from both tables */
  SELECT fee_source_id FROM a_aif
  UNION SELECT fee_source_id FROM a_proxy
) full_list
LEFT JOIN (
  /* First subquery joins to get ids not present in a_aif */
  SELECT fee_source_id AS aif_fee_source_id
  FROM
    a_aif
    LEFT JOIN a_fees ON a_aif.fee_source_id = a_fees.fee_source
) aif ON full_list.fee_source_id = aif_fee_source_id
LEFT JOIN (
  /* Second subquery joins to get ids not present in a_proxy */
  SELECT fee_source_id AS proxy_fee_source_id
  FROM
    a_proxy
    LEFT JOIN a_fees ON a_proxy.fee_source_id = a_fees.fee_source
) proxy ON full_list.fee_source_id = proxy.proxy_fee_source_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc170/3